# Group Testing (probability)

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose there are **1000** cattle ,who might have been affected by a disease. Given: the disease affects a population with a probability of ***p***(take =0.002 as an example). Also it is confirmed by some means that the disease **has** affected the population, i.e. there is at least one cattle which has been affected .The medical department has to find out the ones who have been affected. This will have to be done by blood test.

The blood test is given to be *highly efficient* so much so that it can detect the disease (give *positive* test) even if it had occurred to a *single* animal and the blood of all 1000 animals were mixed and taken together for sampling.

The blood test has to be done in two steps:

Step 1: Divide the 1000 cattle into say $n_1$ groups each having $x_1$ cattle.  For each group, take a portion of the blood sample from each of the $x_1$ cattle in the group and combine them into one sample. Then test each of
the $n_1$ combined samples.

Say $k_1$ of the $n_1$ samples tested positive.

Step 2: Divide each of these $k_1$ groups into further $n_2$ subgroups containing $x_2$ cattle in each sub-group. For each sub-group, take a portion of the blood sample from each of the $x_2$ animals in the sub-group and combine them into one sample. Then test each of the $n_2$ combined samples for each group.

Say $k_{2,i}$ of these $n_2$ subgroups of the ***i*** th group have tested positive, ***i*** $\in$ **{1,..,$k_1$}**.

Final step: Test each of the cattle in each of these $k_{2,i}$ sub-groups to find out the ones which have actually been infected , ***i*** $\in$ **{1,..,$k_1$}**.

*Restrictions:*

1:  $n_1,n_2,x_1,x_2$ all should be $\ge2$;

2: $0\le{k_1}\le{n_1} ; 0\le{k_2}\le{n_2}$

3: $n_1,n_2,x_1,x_2,k_1,k_2$ $\in$ $\Bbb{N}$

Questions:

$\Bbb{A:}$ What will be the maximum number of tests that can be needed by this procedure?

$\Bbb{B:}$ What will be the minimum number of tests that can be needed by this procedure?

$\Bbb{C:}$ Let us define a **worst case scenario** to be the case when the maximum number of steps are required for some given $n_1$ and $n_2$ .What is the probability that a **worst case scenario** occurs given some $n_{1_0}$ and $n_{2_0}$?

**My working:** By performing some elementary calculations, I found out a formula for a worst case scenario $1000\left(1+\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}\right)$ . So to maximize this, we have to minimize $x_1$ and $x_2$ which according to me should have values **4** and **2** respectively as per $\Bbb{A}$. This results in answer of part $\Bbb{A}$ being **1750**.

For minima , I found out an equation , containing $x_1$ and $x_2$ only.Then I assumed $x_1,x_2$ to be real numbers and did $\frac{\delta}{\delta x_1}=0$ and  $\frac{\delta}{\delta x_2}=0$ to get 2 equations for $x_1$ and $x_2$. Solving I got $x_1$=100 and $x_2$=10 . However quite luckily, these values come under the original domain($x_1$ must be a proper factor of 1000 and $x_2$ a proper factor of $x_1$) of $x_1$ and $x_2$. So I found that the answer for part $\Bbb{B}$ is **30**.

I couldn't formulate the third part.

Can someone help me to understand if my first two answers are correct and tell me how to proceed in the third part?